# Finding transfer function of an amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I would like to know if the transfer function i found is correct :
TF = Vs/Vi = -(R-Rg)/(R+Rg)
In my case Rf = R1 = R2 = R ( i just did not find the right schematics ) 
And V1 connected to V2 and equal to Vi .

[image]

Comment: This looks like a homework question. We will want to see all of your work, and you should ask a specific question.

Comment: Mike - you wrote "...I found...". How did you find this result? How did you start?

Comment: Draw the correct schematic. Don't be lazy.

Comment: Please redraw the circuit with the correct symbols and if Rf=R1=R2=R the don't use 3 different labels. If V1 is connected to V2 then show it please and label it Vi.

Comment: looks like an instrumentation amplifier. hope this helps you with google